# Use Apple Maps' Look Around on Linux or Windows?

Tags: maps

Apple recently released wonderful street view style look around photos.

Is there a way to show these on non-Mac-hardware? Like in a Browser?

- Opening https://maps.apple.com does not work on non-Macs.
- I thought I could use an iPad on Browserstack.com App live - but I cannot start the Maps app there.
- https://duckduckgo.com/ uses Apple maps, when you search for a location and switch to maps, but there the Look Around feature is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple is restricting Look Around, and Maps in general, to its devices. There's no way (as far as I know) to use Look Around natively on Windows or on a non-Apple device.

Yet, there are two workarounds to use Look Around on Linux/Windows :

1. Use [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone14promax&osVersion=16.0&scale=75&deviceColor=black), an online iPhone simulator (limited to 60 sec in its free version).
2. Install macOS on a Virtual Machine. It takes a lot of time, and is only legal if the host machine is a Mac.